# How do I enable S3 state?

Tags: configuration, power-management

I'd like to save my computer state in RAM and not on the HDD.
How can I obtain this in 11.04?

Comment: Click on the power icon in your menu bar and click "suspend"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use the power icon in your top panel and choose *Suspend*:

[image]

or run

```
sudo pm-suspend
```

from the command line.